# Getting the max and min price of current chart

Tags: mql4

After performing

```
ChartNavigate(0, CHART_END, -5142);
```

I want to get the max and min price of that particular chart.

I tried

```
ChartGetDouble(0,CHART_PRICE_MAX,0,top)
ChartGetDouble(0,CHART_PRICE_MIN,0,top)
WindowPriceMax
WindowPriceMin
```

None of them gives me the price after the `ChartNavigate`.
What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

### *New*-`MQL4.56789` features may surprise, nevertheless:

Step **0:** always catch **`Chart_OkFLAG`**

```
    bool   Chart_OkFLAG;
    double Chart_min,
           Chart_MAX;
    int    Chart_ToBeMODIFIED          = ChartID();
    int    Chart_ToBeMODIFIED_SubWinID = 0;
    int    Chart_nBarsRelativeSHIFT    = 0;

           Chart_OkFLAG = ChartNavigate( Chart_ToBeMODIFIED,
                                       < CHART_BEGIN       |
                                         CHART_END         |
                                         CHART_CURRENT_POS >,
                                         Chart_nBarsRelativeSHIFT
                                         );
```

If OK: you won the first round, the GUI command has been accepted for being syntactically & context-wise correct. That does not mean, it was executed by the GUI processor. It was just let in, to the tail of the GUI-command-QUEUE.

Step **1:** Enforce it's execution ( wise to think about deferring such processing to some safe place, after mission-critical elements have been fulfilled )

```
   if (  Chart_OkFLAG ){
         WindowRedraw();                                        // ol'-MQL4
         ChartRedraw(                Chart_ToBeMODIFIED );      // new-MQL4
         Chart_min =  ChartPriceMin( Chart_ToBeMODIFIED,
                                     Chart_ToBeMODIFIED_SubWinID
                                     );
         Chart_MAX =  ChartPriceMAX( Chart_ToBeMODIFIED,
                                     Chart_ToBeMODIFIED_SubWinID
                                     );
   }
   else{
      // ERROR HANDLING onChartNavigate(T)ERROR
   }
```

**ALWAYS:** do not hesitate to inline error handlers, even where MQL4 language seems straightforward ( you never know, when that effort pays off by avoiding hours of bug tracking  )

```
double ChartPriceMin( const long Chart_ID           = 0,
                      const int  Chart_SubWindow_ID = 0
                      ) {
                      double result = EMPTY_VALUE;
                      ResetLastError();
                      if (  !ChartGetDouble( Chart_ID,
                                             CHART_PRICE_MIN,
                                             Chart_SubWindow_ID,
                                             result
                                             )
                             ){
                             PrintFormat( "ERROR: Code(%d) in [%s]",
                                           GetLastError(),
                                           __FUNCTION__,
                                           );
                      }
                      return( result );
}
double ChartPriceMAX( const long Chart_ID           = 0,
                      const int  Chart_SubWindow_ID = 0
                      ) {
                      double result = EMPTY_VALUE;
                      ResetLastError();
                      if (  !ChartGetDouble( Chart_ID,
                                             CHART_PRICE_MAX,
                                             Chart_SubWindow_ID,
                                             result
                                             )
                             ){
                             PrintFormat( "ERROR: Code(%d) in [%s]",
                                           GetLastError(),
                                           __FUNCTION__,
                                           );
                      }
                      return( result );
}
```